# Trying to set services to restart ANYTIME they fail. I need this setting to NEVER Expire?

Tags: windows, service, failed, count

When going to Services>Properties>Recovery, how can I configure these settings correctly if I want to ALWAYS restart the service after ANY failure and I need these settings to NEVER expire?
I am not understanding the definition of 'Reset fail count after' setting if you could assist with that too, please?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The reset failure count is the "trigger" for the second recovery action. IF its is set to 0 it will never trigger the second condiction.

Answer (score 0):

Setting "Reset fail count after" to 0 means "reset the fail count to 0 after each failure" until a reboot occurs.

The 0 effectively disables both, the "second failure" and "subsequent failure" actions and you will always get the "first failure" action, until you reboot the machine.